# PIMCore - CSV Import Mapping Parent and Object Title

Tags: pimcore, pimcore-v5

PIMCore - using the Community Edition, how do you map the parent of newly created objects via a CSV import so they don't all go in the root folder you originally selected, also how do you map the object title via the same **CSV** import, I'm currently ending up with objects with the PIMCore ID as the Title (1, 2, 3, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite sure that you need to choose **Filename** as the [Resolver Strategy](https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/User_Documentation/DataObjects/CSV_Import/Resolver/index.html) in the **Resolver Settings** and put correct prefix e.g. (or column which has got full path):
[image: Resolver Settings]

I just tried it on the [Pimcore Advanced Demo](https://demo-advanced.pimcore.org/) with csv like:

```
Title
title1
title2
title3
```

and as you can see seems to work correctly :)

Hope it helps! :) 
BR

Comment: it looks like checking the *Overwrite* checkbox is necessary if you want Pimcore to create not-yet-existing objects

Answer (score 0):

You can use a column for Parent Mapping

```
$document->setParentId(#yourColumn#);
```

Comment: Thanks Dee. I am not a PHP developer though, so where do you put that code. I was trying to achieve the import exclusively via the WebGUI Import Wizard rather than having to develop new PHP code.

Comment: Hey, I guess this isn't possible without extending the importer code or, better, create your own import function. With your own import function, you are also able to put the keys, so you wont have the titles (1,2,3)